# Можно ли открывать доступ к MySql из вне

Tags: mysql

Встал вопрос о доступе к одной базе данных с разных доменов расположенных на разных серверах. Подскажите можно ли открыть доступ к базе данных и безопасно ли это?

Comment: ограничьте доступ только для указанных IP адресов, если беспокоитесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых нужно понимание для чего вы открываете доступ из вне на такой сервис как доступ к БД: обычно доступ к какому-то сервису закрывается каким-то дополнительным слоем REST api; 1С Предприятием (это для примера) или ещё как-то. А вот уже этот слой публикуется для доступа.

Во вторых нужно понимание кому вы открываете доступ: ограниченному кругу лиц с известными внешними статическими ip-адресами или клиентам с динамическими адресами (де-факто для всего интернета)

В третьих нужно понимание в каком состоянии находится открываемый вами сервис: давно ли он обновлен от известных уязвимостей; регулярно ли он обновляется; поддерживает ли шифрование (так как в открытом виде передавать поток данных от базы данных до клиентского приложения через весь Интернет - точно плохая идея)

в четвертых нужно понимание какие критически-важные службы расположены на этом же сервере и могут в случае чего тоже пострадать, или какие критически-важные службы расположены в легкой досягаемости с этого сервера. В идеале все важные сервисы не публикуемые в инет должны находиться внутри локальной сети, а службы публикуемые в инет должны находиться в демилитаризованной зоне организованной через строгую фильтрацию трафика на входе и выходе.

В общей схеме лучше не публиковать службу, а публиковать vpn доступ к службе. Что бы клиент соединялся с демилитаризованной зоной посредством шифруемого канала vpn, а уже внутри канала соединялся с сервером БД (с использованием шифрования), а сам сервер БД был обновлен и регулярно обновлялся.